# Client Unique Generated ID vs Database unique id

Tags: php, software-design

For distributed system it is recommended to generate unique ids from Client side.

Meaning that if I am on PHP, the ID of the entity that is going to be persisted in DB will have its ID before going to the database.

This allows to horizontally scale the infrastructure, as well as decoupled from the Database storage system that you are using.

However, if I do it and I use for example a uuid library, the ID will be a string, if I have big tables doing joins the string ids will perform really bad.

So my question is what is the recommended approach for this? I noticed a company like Facebook use instead Integer Ids, they seem to be prefixed and post-fixed.

Does it make sense then to do something like: first 4 character is the server originating the id, the other 15 a random id + last 4 character a random number from 0000 to 9999 ?

Is there a name for this type of pattern/library?

Answer (score 1):

Cramming business information into a key is a business or natural key.  Arbitrary keys (random, sequential, etc) are called surrogate keys.  I'm not a big fan of including natural information in ID's.  Just to note a few issues with using natural keys in a database as the actual identifier:

- If you have independent or semi-independent entities producing their own internally unique ID's, for example, the characteristics of the ID's may change over time, and perhaps not all at once for all of the independent entities, and suddenly you may find yourself versioning ID's.
- Depending on the type of data, the entities might change.  For example, if the entities are countries and the countries split in two or merge, your ID space is suddenly a mess.
- If business data is corrected or changed, you have to change the ID
  everywhere it is used in the database.
- Inevitably, as you use the database, you will find a critical piece of business data NOT in the ID, and be tempted to add it in to your key.

In most cases, I prefer to have a database generated numeric key - for simplicity, not performance - in tables as a surrogate key and a side table with the natural key data.  This makes it easier to add new information types, deal with variations, exceptions, errors, changes, etc in the natural data.  I find many if not most of my queries don't even require that demographic information.  Obviously when you are interacting with the various entities you use their ID space.

Also, unless I run into trouble with performance - and that is almost always indexing issues or poorly thought out queries, rather than data  type issues - I try to set the database up in the most appropriate way and let the database optimizers do their job.